# Remove all data in a DF by group based on a condition (pandas,python3)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas DF like this:

```
    User      Enrolled    Time   
     1           0         12
     1           0         1
     1           1         2
     1           1         3
     2           1         3
     2           0         4
     2           1         1
     3           0         2
     3           0         3
     3           1         4
     4           0         1
```

I want to remove all rows of a users information after they have enrolled.  Each users chance to enroll is timed in order.  Expected output to look like this:

```
    User        Enrolled       Time
     1            0             12
     1            0             1
     1            1             2
     2            1             3
     3            0             2
     3            0             3
     3            1             4
```

Hoping someone could help me!

EDIT: Example based on comment for correct answer:

```
       User        Enrolled       Time
         4            0             1
         4            0             2
         4            0             3
         5            0             1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a `groupby` followed by an `apply` which does the correct logic for each user. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[ 1,  0, 12],
                   [ 1,  0,  1],
                   [ 1,  1,  2],
                   [ 1,  1,  3],
                   [ 2,  1,  3],
                   [ 2,  0,  4],
                   [ 2,  1,  1],
                   [ 3,  0,  2],
                   [ 3,  0,  3],
                   [ 3,  1,  4]],
                  columns=['User', 'Enrolled', 'Time'])

def filter_enrollment(df):
    enrolled = df[df.Enrolled == 1].index.min()
    return df[df.index <= enrolled]

result = df.groupby('User').apply(filter_enrollment).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The result is:

```
>>> print(result)
   User  Enrolled  Time
0     1         0    12
1     1         0     1
2     1         1     2
3     2         1     3
4     3         0     2
5     3         0     3
6     3         1     4
```

Here I'm assuming your rows are in order of time. If you want to expliticly filter by the time column instead just change `index` to `Time` in the filter function.

Edit: to get the answer of the edited question, you can change the filter function to something like this:

```
def filter_enrollment(df):
    enrolled = df[df.Enrolled == 1].index.min()
    if pd.isnull(enrolled):
        return df
    else:
        return df[df.index <= enrolled]
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works perfectly :)  I have accepted your answer as it answered my original question.  Sorry to come back with another question, I was wondering if there was any simple way to keep in those users who NEVER enrolled at all (e.g. user 4 has 0,0,0)?  I have updated my original question with an example.

Comment: For that situation, you could change the filtering function. If there are any entries with enrolled==1, then return the current result. Else, return the first row.

Comment: What if there are multiple rows that are variable (e.g some people have had 3 chances to enroll and haven't, others have only had 1)?

Comment: I have placed an edit at the bottom of my original question -- apologies for not including this secondary ask in the original question and appreciate your help!